# How to checkout a local branch from a remote's one with the same name?

Tags: git, android-studio

Is there anyone knows how to
**checkout a local branch from a remote's one with the same name with more convenient command?**

I usually do it by typing remote branch's name in param manually

Ex:
*git checkout -b remotebranchName origin/remotebranchName*

Or do it in Android Studio by
*Check out as a new remote branch*
[image]

Is there any short equivalent command in Git ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the short version is:

```
git checkout remotebranchName
```

As mentioned in [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt):

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to:

```
git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

---

With [Git 2.23+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), the [new command `git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) would also create the branch and track its upstream branch in one line:

```
git switch remotebranchName
```

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to:
>
> ```
> $ git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```